# Function within an if block

Tags: function, if-statement

A function called within an if block does not return any values. Test code enclosed

```
    //@version=5
    indicator("Function Tester")
    fun(x, y) =>
        a = x+y
        b = x-y
        [a, b]

    c = 0
    d = 0

    if (open > close)
        [c , d] = fun(open, close)

    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(c) + " " + str.tostring(d))
```

Comment: What language is this? What are `open`, `close`, `label`, `bar_index` and , `high`? Is this a [mcve]? How do you run this?

Comment: This is in Pinescript